# Firebase Cloud Functions(Stripe: AddPaymentSource)

Tags: java, android, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I have an Android and iOS application that uses Firebase cloud functions with Stripe to process payments.

On the client side I handle the token operation and then write to the realtime database. When done writing the addPaymentSource cloud function triggers which stores that payment source for future transactions.

Interesting enough the process of creating a token on iOS and then saving that output to my server works as expected. My problem comes along when trying to duplicate my iOS implementation into my Android application. The Firebase cloud function triggers as expected but it is outputting an error to my server.

Error found in server:

```
"The source hash must include an 'object' key indicating what type of source to create."
```

Client code:

```
public void tokenizePaymentFields(){
    Stripe stripe = new Stripe(getApplicationContext(), stripePublishableKey);

    final Card stripeCard  = new Card(validCard.getCardNumber()
    ,Integer.valueOf(validCard.getExpiredDate().substring(0,2)),Integer.valueOf(validCard.getExpiredDate().substring(3,5)),validCard.getCvvCode());

    if (!stripeCard.validateCard()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "There was an error validating your card.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show();
        return;
    }
    stripe.createToken(
            stripeCard,
            new TokenCallback() {
                public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                    // Send token to your server
                    pushToServer(token);
                }
                public void onError(Exception error) {
                    // Show localized error message
                    activitySubmitCreditCardBinding.progressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getLocalizedMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Stripe(Firebase Cloud Functions):
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe

Answer (score 2):

Rather than sending the entire [token object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) to your server, you should simply send the token's [`id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object-id), like this:

```
public void onSuccess(Token token) {
    // Send token to your server
    pushToServer(token.getId());
}
```

In your server-side (Firebase) code, the [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) expects only a token ID in the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-source) parameter, not a full token object.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help.